# Переключатель с выбором цвета на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь собрать небольшой конструктор на jQuery. Есть секция выбора цвета. В этой секции выбирается два параметра: внешний цвет и внутренний. Делаю это с помощью списка, просто добавляя `class="selected"` к элементу.

Второй, внешний цвет, под спойлером потому что их много.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function ProductBuilder(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.colors = this.element.children('.section-colors');
    this.bindEvents(); // Событие связующего компоновщика
  }
  ProductBuilder.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    var self = this;

    // Определяет клики на элементах кастомизации
    this.colors.on('click', '.section-colors-customizer a', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      self.customizeModel($(this));
    });
    this.colors.$('.spoiler-text').hide();
    this.colors.on('click', '.spoiler', function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('folded').toggleClass('unfolded').next().slideToggle();
    });
  }
  ProductBuilder.prototype.customizeModel = function(target) {
    var parent = target.parent('li')
    index = parent.index();
    target.parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').end();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-colors">
  <h2>Внутренний цвет</h2>
  <ul class="section-colors-customizer" id="internal">
    <li data-content="Белый" data-price="0" class="selected"><a data-color="white" href="#0">Белый</a></li>
    <li data-content="Серый" data-price="1"><a data-color="703805" href="#0">Серый</a></li>
    <li data-content="Чёрный" data-price="2"><a data-color="305405" href="#0">Чёрный</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
  <h2>Внешний цвет</h2>
  <div class="spoiler-wrapper">
    <div class="spoiler folded"><span>Показать все цвета</span></div>
    <div class="spoiler-text">
      <ul class="section-colors-customizer" id="external">
        <li data-content="Белый" data-price="0" class="selected"><a data-color="white" href="#0">Белый</a></li>
        <li data-content="Серый" data-price="1"><a data-color="703805" href="#0">Серый</a></li>
        <li data-content="Чёрный" data-price="2"><a data-color="305405" href="#0">Чёрный</a></li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Что только не пробовал, но ни переключатель, ни спойлер не работают. Наверняка ошибка где-то в переходах между функциями, но я никак не могу её найти.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь работает спойлер и клики.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log('Ready');

  function ProductBuilder(element) {
    this.element = element;
    // children is not a function
    this.colors = this.element.children; //('.section-colors');
    this.bindEvents(); // Событие связующего компоновщика
  }

  ProductBuilder.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    var self = this;

    // Определяет клики на элементах кастомизации
    //this.colors <-- Error to call on()
    $([].concat.apply([], this.colors)).on('click', '.section-colors-customizer a', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      self.customizeModel($(this));
      console.log('Clicked cutomizer');
    });
    //this.colors. <-- Error to call on()
    $.each(this.colors, function(el) {
      $(this).find('.spoiler-text').hide();
    });
    // this.colors
    $([].concat.apply([], this.colors)).on('click', '.spoiler', function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('folded').toggleClass('unfolded').next().slideToggle();
    });
  }
  ProductBuilder.prototype.customizeModel = function(target) {
    var parent = target.parent('li')
    index = parent.index();
    target.parent('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected').end();
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

  //Demo element
  var el = document.querySelector('.section-colors');
  var pb = new ProductBuilder(el);
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="section-colors">
    <h2>Внутренний цвет</h2>
    <ul class="section-colors-customizer" id="internal">
      <li data-content="Белый" data-price="0" class="selected"><a data-color="white" href="#0">Белый</a></li>
      <li data-content="Серый" data-price="1"><a data-color="703805" href="#0">Серый</a></li>
      <li data-content="Чёрный" data-price="2"><a data-color="305405" href="#0">Чёрный</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
    <h2>Внешний цвет</h2>
    <div class="spoiler-wrapper">
      <div class="spoiler folded"><span>Показать все цвета</span></div>
      <div class="spoiler-text">
        <ul class="section-colors-customizer" id="external">
          <li data-content="Белый" data-price="0" class="selected"><a data-color="white" href="#0">Белый</a></li>
          <li data-content="Серый" data-price="1"><a data-color="703805" href="#0">Серый</a></li>
          <li data-content="Чёрный" data-price="2"><a data-color="305405" href="#0">Чёрный</a></li>
          ...
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

P.S.: На весь экран.

Comment: Спасибо, общую идею и ошибки я понял. Доработал немного код, чтобы внутренний цвет тоже переключался и всё заработало.